# Extracting a list inside a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am having problems extracting a list from a list.

```
(defun delete (a l)
    (cond
       ((null l) nil)
       ((eq (car l) a) (delete a (cdr l)))
       (t (cons (car l) (delete a (cdr l))))))
```

It deletes whatever is 'a' in a list l but if l consists of another list and a is in that inner list then my program can't reach inside that inner list.

Comment: Don't name your function DELETE. That name is already taken by Common Lisp for a built-in function.

Comment: The default equality test should also be EQL and not EQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not only one possible solution, but I will stay close to your code. Since this is homework, I will not give you a working answer, but I will try to give you some things to think about, and give detailed pointers:

Try to understand what your code does and what you really want it to do:

```
(defun remove-all (a l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((eql (car l) a) (delete a (cdr l)))
        (t (cons (car l) (delete a (cdr l))))))
```

(Renamed to `remove-all` because `delete` is already taken, and re-indented in a sane manner.)

For flat lists, the code seems to work; but how about nested lists? Let's look at an easy example:

1. What will happen if you evaluate `(remove-all 1 '((1)))`?
2. What do you want to happen for that input?
3. How can you achieve it?

Let's take a look:

1. What happens:

   - The list is not `null`, go on
   - The `car` is not `eq` to `1` go on
   - `'(1)` gets `cons`ed to `(remove-all '())`, yielding `'((1))`

   So, it failed to recognize that the `car` is itself a list which should be searched for matching elements. The problem seems to lie between step one and step two.
2. What should be done:

   - Check, if the `car` is itself a list
   - If yes, invoke `remove-all` on it
   - Then, `cons` the result to the `cdr`, which also needs to be "cleaned" (Hint: But only *if* there is something to `cons`)
3. How exactly?

   - Add a `cond` clause which does the things mentioned under 2 -- Left as homework

Answer (score 3):

You need another clause where you test if the item is a list and when true also recurses into the sublist.